# Return 2 Decimal Places In Function Array

Tags: javascript, return, decimal

I would like to return an array of items to 2 decimal places.

Example- Return with 5 for "Enter years", 1000 for "Enter iniInvest", 10 for "Enter interest", and 1000 for "Enter yearlyInv":
 **1100,2310,3641,5105.1,6715.610000000001**

I would like the array items to end in 2 decimal places. 1100.00, 2310.00, 3641.00, 5105.10, 6715.61

I have attempted a few things including

```
return totalArry.toFixed(2);
return totalArry[].toFixed(2);
```

Neither of these resolved the issue.  I've done some searching but I don't understand enough to know how to convert some of the answers I found to work with my code.

```
function investCalc() {
    for(i=1; i<years; i++) {
        totalYear += parseFloat(yearlyInv); 
        totalInt = parseFloat(totalYear) * parseFloat(interest/100); 
        totalYear += parseFloat(totalInt); 
        totalArry.push(totalYear);
    }
    return totalArry.toFixed(2);
}
var years = prompt("Enter years");
var iniInvest = prompt("Enter iniInvest");
var interest = prompt("Enter interest");
var yearlyInv = prompt("Enter yearlyInv");
var totalInt = parseFloat(iniInvest) * parseFloat(interest/100); 
var totalYear = parseFloat(iniInvest) + parseFloat(totalInt); 
var totalArry = [totalYear]; 

alert(investCalc());
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Array is for collection of elements. I don't understand what you mean by "return an array of items with 2 decimal places"

Comment: Agree with @RobertC.Holland, it should be clearer. Could you provide some input variables and the equivalent expected outputs?

Comment: Yes if you enter  5 for "Enter Years", 1000 for "Enter iniInvest", 10 for "Enter interest", and 1000 for "Enter yearlyInv" it will return (1100,2310,3641,5105.1,6715.610000000001).  I would like these to stay within .00 decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each element of the array to have 2 decimal places, you need to call `.toFixed(2)` on each element, not on the array variable. You can do it before you push an element to the array: `totalArry.push(totalYear.toFixed(2));`

Note that `toFixed` returns a string, so you will get an array of strings. If you want an array of numbers, you can use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()): `totalArry.push(+totalYear.toFixed(2));`

```js
function investCalc() {
    for(let i = 1; i < years; i++) {
        totalYear += parseFloat(yearlyInv); 
        totalInt = parseFloat(totalYear) * parseFloat(interest/100); 
        totalYear += parseFloat(totalInt); 
        totalArry.push(+totalYear.toFixed(2));
    }
    return totalArry;
}
var years = prompt("Enter years");
var iniInvest = prompt("Enter iniInvest");
var interest = prompt("Enter interest");
var yearlyInv = prompt("Enter yearlyInv"); 
var totalInt = parseFloat(iniInvest) * parseFloat(interest/100); 
var totalYear = parseFloat(iniInvest) + parseFloat(totalInt); 
var totalArry = [+totalYear.toFixed(2)]; 

console.log(investCalc());
```

Comment: Thank You.  This was just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Admin666 I was glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You need to restrict the float number you are pushing into the array to two decimal places not the entire array. Here is the code.

```
function investCalc() {
for(i=1; i<years; i++) {
    totalYear += parseFloat(yearlyInv); 
    totalInt = parseFloat(totalYear) * parseFloat(interest/100); 
    totalYear += parseFloat(totalInt); 
    totalYear = parseFloat(totalYear).toFixed(2); //round or pad with zeros to two decimal places
    totalArry.push(totalYear);                   //Then push into the array.
    }
return totalArry;
 }
}
var years = prompt("Enter years");
var iniInvest = prompt("Enter iniInvest");
var interest = prompt("Enter interest");
var yearlyInv = prompt("Enter yearlyInv");
var totalInt = parseFloat(iniInvest) * parseFloat(interest/100); 
var totalYear = parseFloat(iniInvest) + parseFloat(totalInt); 
totalYear = totalYear.toFixed(2);
var totalArry = [totalYear]; 

alert(investCalc());
```